# Reading a short text file to a string in swift

Tags: swift, nsstring

I need to read the contents of a short text file in my Swift program. I did this:

```
var err: NSError?
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("cards", ofType: "ini")
let content = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

My problem is that I can't use the error reporting. If I change that last line to this:

```
let content = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: err)
```

The compiler complains "Extra argument 'contentsOfFile' in call". That makes zero sense to me, maybe someone else can figure it out?

Comment: where u able to find the solution

Comment: The solution is below. Pass `err` by reference: `&err`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At a first glance I'd say that you have to pass the `err` variable by reference:

```
let content = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)
```

Comment: That appears to be correct. And, if I may say so, obscure.

Comment: Well it's not so obscure... `error` is supposed to be set from within the initializer, so in order for it to be able to modify you have to pass a reference and not a copy. Btw when you see a function parameter being prefixed with the `inout` modifier, that it means yo have to pass by reference, using the `&` operator (which stands for "reference to")

Comment: a) the error is clearly not that contentOfFile is an extra parameter. The error is wrong

b) I am trying out Swift specifically because I wanted to rid myself of BS exactly like this. It is the method declaration and compiler that should handle pass-by considerations, not the caller.

Comment: Ok, if you are referring to the error messages, I totally agree -actually after you work with swift a little bit, you can figure out what a cryptic and unrelated error message really means. In your case, what I think is happening is that it fails to properly detect what's the init overload you're trying to call, the compiler select another one, for which there's no `contentsOfFile` parameter.

Comment: This does not appear to be working anymore, and the overloading method contents of File is not in the reference anymore

Answer (score 18):

Following the new error handling introduced into iOS 9/Swift 2, a solution for this that works for me is:

```
let fileLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("filename", ofType: "txt")!
let text : String
do
{
    text = try String(contentsOfFile: fileLocation)
}
catch
{
    text = ""
}
```

text will contain the file contents or be empty in the case of an error.

Comment: Indeed, a real improvement. Lots of others too.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve the error by using it in this way :

```
let content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

or if wanted to use error reporting then

```
var err: NSError?
let content = String.stringWithContentsOfFile(path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)
```